# Redirect and Rewrite to remove .html from url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a really basic rewrite rule that I've been banging my head against the wall trying to achieve. I have a static HTML site that I want pretty URLs for.

So, I want `/something` to serve `/something.html` and I also want to redirect (externally) from `/something.html` to `/something` as to not be penalized on SEO for hosting duplicate content.

I don't want to use Multiviews and I don't want to use `<rel cannonical="">`

This is what I currently have.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

It results in an infinite redirect loop.

It seems to me that the first rule keeps matching even after the requested URL doesn't end in .html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your rules will cause redirect loop due to use of `REQUEST_URI` (via `RewriteRule`) which changes after application of a rule.

You can use:

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=302,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

- `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

Comment: Let's say I request /something.html. The first time through I should hit the first rule and externally redirect to /something. On that request, why does the first rule even match? Or does the second rule get executed, then the first rule gets run again?

Comment: Yes first rules does 301 to `/something` and then 2nd rule changes that internally to `/something.html` and then 1st rule runs again and makes it `/something` and so on. Just remember that `mod_rewrite` keeps running your loop as long as there is a matching rule.

Comment: Even when you have the [L] flag?

Comment: `L` flag only ends current loop. In programming equivalent that acts as `continue` instead of `break` in a `for loop`.

Comment: What does all that `\s/+(?:index)?` mean in the RewriteCond?

Comment: `(?:index)?` is being used to redirect `http://doamain.com/index.html` to `http://doamain.com/`. `\s` is to match space before the URL start in `THE_REQUEST` variable.

Comment: Ah, I see, why do you need to match the index any differently than every other page?

Comment: It is just that site admins prefer `http://doamain.com/` instead of `http://doamain.com/index.html` (`index.html` is default file to show on most websites)

Comment: but doesn't that get caught by the (.*?) anyway? Why do you need that?

Comment: Simply changing to `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html [NC]` works just fine. Thanks for explaining how everything works and leading me in the right direction. Basically, if the original request includes .html, you need to redirect, otherwise you don't.

Comment: Yes that's correct, use of `%{THE_REQUEST}` is key here.